# SQL ALL operator does nothing. What is it used for?

Tags: sql, sql-server, operator-keyword

I don't understand the use of ALL operator in SQL Server. In the following example, ALL doesn't seem to do much since when I remove it, I get the same results. Do I really have to use it?

```
 SELECT *
    FROM EMPLOYEE
    WHERE Salary > ALL (
                    SELECT AVG(Salary) 
                    FROM EMPLOYEE);
```

So my question is, what does ALL do, when should I use it and is it necessary?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You get one result back from `SELECT AVG(Salary) FROM Employee`, so you're executing the all on a single item. Naturally you're going to get the same result here with or without it.

Comment: Sorry I edited the code there was a mistake. I changed Salairy to Salary

Answer (score 3):

From [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_any_all.asp):

> The `ALL` operator:
>
> - returns a boolean value as a result
> - returns TRUE if ALL of the subquery values meet the condition
> - is used with SELECT, WHERE and HAVING statements
>
> ALL means that the condition will be true only if the operation is true for all values in the range.

In your query, `SEELCT AVG(Salary) FROM Employee` returns a single result, so you're comparing each individual employee's salary to "all" of the averages (for which you have one average). This is why your query doesn't need the `ALL`.

If you had a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE Salary > ALL (SELECT SomeValue FROM SomeTable);
```

And the SomeValue values of SomeTable were:

```
5000
2000
800
```

Then you would only get results from `Employee` where `Salary > 5000 AND Salary > 2000 AND Salary > 800` (effectively Salary > 5000).

Borrowing [an example from sqltutorial.org](https://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-all/), you might want to find all employees whose salaries are higher than the salary of employees working in a specific department. Obviously the employees that this query finds will not be in that department:

```
SELECT 
    first_name, last_name, salary
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    salary > ALL (SELECT 
            salary
        FROM
            employees
        WHERE
            department_id = 2)
ORDER BY salary;
```